# jQuery each always returns last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop the .each() selecting the last value each time it runs?

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

$("#list li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("one")) {
    addedClass = "red";
  } else {
    addedClass = "blue";
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  $("#results").append("<p class=" + addedClass + ">" + array[i] + "</p>");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/120678/)

Comment: You're probably trying to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3gv8ak4a/

Comment: you defined only one common variable addedClass and obviously on exit of loop it will retain the value set during its last iteration

Comment: @Titus Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge all in one cycle.

Try this solution:

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

$("#list li").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("one")) {
    addedClass = "red";
    $("#results").append("<p class=" + addedClass + ">" + index + "</p>");
  } else {
    addedClass = "blue";
    $("#results").append("<p class=" + addedClass + ">" + index + "</p>");
  }
});
```

Comment: You have a repeating statement which you could just move after the `if` `else` statement.